# How to find files with a name recursively and bring the whole path?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to find the files and directories containing the name "fink" (Part of file name is "fink". Not contents) and print their whole path from Root.

Whats the command for it in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find:

```
find . -name "*fink*" -print
```

To find and list:

```
find . -name "*fink*" |xargs ls -l
```

To find and print full path

```
find / -name "*fink*" -print
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find only (regular) files OR directories containing "fink" in their names and print their path from root:

```
find / \( -type f -or -type d \) -name \*fink\* -print
```

and to list them:

```
find / \( -type f -or -type d \) -name \*fink\* -ls
```

in both cases you might want to add `2>/dev/null` at the end to get rid of the errors (especially permission denied from /proc).